# react-router onClick not firing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, browserify, react-router

I am trying out server side rendering with react-router and coming unstuck. No click handlers within react-router's `<Handler />` fire, but lifecycle events such as `componentDidMount` do.

The server receives a request, runs it through react-router and spits out the HTML fine:

routes.js

```
var routes = (
    <Route handler={App}>
        <Route name='page' handler={Page} path='/page' />
        <Route name='other' handler={Other} path='/other' />
    </Route>
);
```

server.js

```
var App = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return (
            <div>
                <RouteHandler />
            </div>
        )
    }
});
```

index.jade

```
extends layout
block content
  div#app!= markup
  div#test!= test
```

You can see there are 2 `React` components here; `content` (the resulting view from react-router) and `test` (simple button with onClick)

Once the HTML is loaded on the client, my `client.js` script runs which enables `React` to check and bind to the components:

```
function run(){
    Router.run(routes, Router.HistoryLocation, function (Handler, state) {
        React.render(<Handler />, document.getElementById('app'));
        React.render(<Test />, document.getElementById('test'));
    });
}
run();
```

The issue is that **none** of the `onClick` handlers run for **any** components inside of `<Handler />`, including the `react-router` component `<Link />`. However `<Test />` **does** fire perfectly fine.

Here is the markup for one of the pages which would be inside `<Handler />`:

```
var Page = React.createClass({
    componentDidMount:function(){
      window.setTimeout(function(){
          //The runs fine
          console.log('component has connect properly');
      },500);
    },
    render: function () {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1 onClick={this.test}>Page</h1>
                <Link to='other' >Other</Link>
                <button onClick={this.alertIt}>Alert</button>
            </div>
        )
    },
    test:function(){
        console.log('testing');
    },
    alertIt: function () {        
        alert('Page');
    }
});
```

And here is the working `<Test />` component:

```
var Test = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.test}>Test</button>
            </div>
        )
    },
    test:function(){
        alert('testing');
    }
});
```

**Update 1**

Even if I remove the server side rendering and render the `<Handler />` just on the client the issue still persists.

**Updated 2**

The page example above is rendering within a parent component:

```
var App = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return (
            <div>
                <RouteHandler />
            </div>
        )
    }
});
```

**Updated 3**

I copied this **without** using `Browserify`, having `React` and `react-router` as global objects and it works perfectly fine...

**Solution A**

By adding `browserify-shim` to my build process and setting it to use `React` and `react-router` from the `window` instead of `node_modules` it works. This is not the cleanest solution but still fits the isomorphic stuff nicely. I would still like to find out why using `React` from `node_modules` causes this issue though.

browserify-shim config:

```
"browserify": {
    "transform":[
      "browserify-shim"
    ]
  },
  "browserify-shim": {
    "React": "global:React",
    "react-router": "global:ReactRouter"
  }
```

**Update 4**

After some playing around it seems it's only `react-router` which isn't playing nicely with `Browserify`. Simple `React` and `Browserify` works fine.

Comment: did you tried to use `reactify` with your `Browserify` ? https://github.com/andreypopp/reactify